# Convince grep to output all lines, not just those with matches

Tags: grep, highlighting

Say I have the following file:

```
$ cat test

test line 1
test line 2
line without the search word
another line without it
test line 3 with two test words
test line 4
```

By default, `grep` returns each line that contains the search term:

```
$ grep test test

test line 1
test line 2
test line 3 with two test words
test line 4
```

Passing the `--color` parameter to `grep` will make it highlight the portion of the line that matches the search expression, but it still only returns lines that contain the expression. Is there a way to get `grep` to output every line in the source file, but highlight the matches?

My current terrible hack to accomplish this (at least on files that don't have 10000+ consecutive lines with no matches) is:

```
$ grep -B 9999 -A 9999 test test
```

[image: Screenshot of the two commands]

If `grep` can't accomplish this, is there another command-line tool that offers the same functionality? I've fiddled with [`ack`](https://beyondgrep.com/), but it doesn't seem to have an option for it either.

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighting The top answer is the same on both.

Comment: You can use `-C 9999` in place of `-A 9999 -B 9999`.I always do: `grep -C 9999 pattern file`

Comment: Try **sed**. For example, here's how to **highlight + return exit code**:  https://askubuntu.com/a/1200851/670392

Comment: `-C9999` (or `-C99` for a short input) might actually be high up on the list of elegance/availability, and gives the right return value if it finds a match.  The only downside is it won't print anything if it doesn't find one.

Answer (score 233, accepted):

```
grep --color -E "test|$" yourfile
```

What we're doing here is matching against the `$` pattern and the test pattern, obviously `$` doesn't have anything to colourize so only the test pattern gets color.  The `-E` just turns on extended regex matching.

You can create a function out of it easily like this:

```
highlight () { grep --color -E "$1|$" "${@:1}" ; }
```

Comment: That's freaking awesome!

Comment: And as a function: `highlight () { grep --color -E "$1|$" $2 ; }`. Usage: `highlight test yourfile`

Comment: @StefanLasiewski: `"$2"` should also be quoted.

Comment: Better could be: `highlight () { grep --color -E "$1|$" "$@" }` which allows files with whitespace in their names *and* multiple files.

Comment: @MikeDeSimone - But that will also have `"$1"` in the files. Use `highlight () { grep --color -E "$1|$" "${@:1}" }`

Comment: I have my `LESS` environment set to (amongst other flags) `-r`, so I've modified the alias to `grep --color=always ...` so long files can be piped to less and still have the highlight :)

Comment: What do you mean when you say you're matching against the "$ pattern"? Doesn't the `$` character mean end of line?

Comment: I came up with this `${@:2}` with bash because you dont want the first argument to be repeated in the list files to check. `highlight() { grep --color -E -- "$1|\$" "${@:2}"; }`. Note the `--` also to signigy that arguments with dash are done, so if you search a pattern line `-something` its still working.

Comment: I find the same result as @Lynch. Does the answer as written work for anyone?

Comment: you don't need the dollar after the OR - `grep --color -E "test|" yourfile`   ... that might help cuz now you don't need to escape in the double-quote string

Comment: You can also use the shorter version `highlight () { grep --color -E "$1|$" ; }` if you only want to pipe into it, like `helm deploy | highlight configured` for example.

Comment: @Lynch: reverse the order of arguments to grep to not need the -- :  `highlight() { grep --color -E "^|$1" "${@:2}"; }`

Comment: @OlivierDulac the `--` are not something you would want to remove. It is something to make your script more robust. You don't have to fight the double dash. What if `"${@:2}"` == `--something-funny`?

Comment: Totally power hack

Answer (score 46):

```
ack --passthru --color string file
```

for Ubuntu and Debian, use ack-grep instead of ack

```
ack-grep --passthru --color string file
```

Comment: Oh, that's quite obviously in the man page; I'm blind. Thanks

Comment: the pattern for grap may be specified explicitly with `--regexp string`; the ack/ack-grep equivalent is `--match string`

Comment: To simulate `ack --passthru` with perl : `grep_passthrough () { ! perl -ne "print; \$e ||= /$@/; END{{exit \$e}}"; }`

Comment: `ack --passthru` also works on streams! For example, `ifconfig | ack --passthru inet`

Answer (score 18):

Another way to do this *properly* and *portably* with `grep` (besides using two regexes with alternation as in the accepted answer) is via the null pattern (and respectively null string).
It should work equally well with both `-E` and `-F` switches since, [per the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html#tag_20_55):

```
-E
    Match using extended regular expressions. 
    [...] A null ERE shall match every line.
```

and

```
-F
    Match using fixed strings.
    [...] A null string shall match every line.
```

So it's simply a matter of running

```
grep -E -e '' -e 'pattern' infile
```

and respectively

```
grep -F -e '' -e 'string' infile
```

Comment: Or just `grep -F -e '' -e 'string'`.

Comment: It works for me with GNU grep 2.25, busybox grep and the heirloom toolchest one.

Comment: OK, my bad, `seq 3 | grep -F -e '' -e 2` does output only 2 in 2.27 (and 2.26, but not 2.25, and not in the git head). Only with `-F` (not without or with -E). IOW, only 2.26 and 2.27 seem to have the bug and only with -F.

Comment: Note that `seq 3 | grep  -F -e '' -e '' -e 2`  does seem to work as well with 2.27

Comment: The method given in this answer is simple, correct, and [seems quite fast](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23873140/). [As you say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340320/bash-show-the-contents-of-a-text-file-with-every-occurrence-of-a-word-highligh/340322?noredirect=1#comment601814_340322), it works automatically with `-F`, alleviating the need to worry about what characters appear in *`string`*. You might want to mention `--color`; as this answer floats up on the page (when viewed by votes), more people may end up reading it before the other answers.

Comment: To preserve highlighting of matches in pipes, do `grep -F -e 'string' -e ''`.

Answer (score 12):

I have the following function that I use for such things:

```
highlight () {
    perl -pe "s/$1/\e[1;31;43m$&\e[0m/g"
}
```

Internally it looks kind of ugly, it's nice and easy to use, like so:

```
cat some_file.txt | highlight some_word
```

or, for a slightly more real-world example:

```
tail -f console.log | highlight ERROR
```

You can change the colors to anything you like (which might be hard with grep--I'm not sure) by changing the `1` and `31` and `43` (after `\e[`) to different values.  The [codes](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x329.html) to use are [all](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) over [the place](http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=ANSI+terminal+color+codes&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), but here's a quick intro: the 1 bolds the text, the `31` makes it red, and the `43` gives a yellow background.  `32` or `33` would be different colors, and `44` or `45` would be different backgrounds: you get the idea.  You can even make it blink (with a `5`) if you're so inclined.

This doesn't use any special Perl modules, and Perl is *nearly* ubiquitous, so I would expect it to work just about anywhere.  The grep solution is very clever, but the --color switch on grep is not available everywhere.  For instance, I just tried this solution on a Solaris box running bash, and another running ksh, and my local Mac OS X machine running zsh.  All worked just fine.  Solaris choked on the `grep --color` solution, however.

Also, ack is awesome, and I recommend it to anyone who hasn't yet discovered it, but I've had some issues installing it on a few of the many servers I work on.  (I forget why: I think related to Perl modules it required.)

Since I don't think I've *ever* worked on a Unix box that *didn't* have Perl installed (with the exception of embedded-type systems, Linksys routers, and such) I'd say this is pretty much a universally useable solution.

Comment: I like this solution because it does just what you want rather than bend and existing tool like grep which is more indirect.  It also gives you more flexibility should you want to change the behavior.  (Although just a note you can change the colors with `grep` with the env var `GREP_COLORS` which uses the same SGR codes).

Comment: Also just a note that the colors are reset with `\e[0m` after the match and so this will also clear any existing colorization in the input stream.  That's also true of `grep`, however.  If you need to handle input that's already colorized, you might consider wrapping your match text with the terminal controls `tput smso` and `tput rmso` instead.

Answer (score 7):

#### [`ripgrep`](https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

Use `ripgrep` with its `--passthru` parameter:

```
rg --passthru pattern file.txt
```

It's one of the [fastest grepping tools](http://blog.burntsushi.net/ripgrep/), since it's built on top of [Rust's regex engine](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/regex) which uses finite automata, SIMD and aggressive literal optimizations to make searching very fast.

> `--passthru` - Print both matching and non-matching lines.
>
> Another way to achieve a similar effect is by modifying your pattern to match the empty string. For example, if you are searching using `rg foo` then using `rg "^|foo"` instead will emit every line in every file searched, but only occurrences of foo will be highlighted. This flag enables the same behavior without needing to modify the pattern.

Comment: This is the most helpful answer, especially since the exit code isn't zero when the pattern wasn't matched.


For example: `grep --color -E "test|$" yourfile` just highlights all occurrences of `"test"` in the file and even when there are no matches, it still returns `0` which is counter-intuitive.

However: `rg --passthru test yourfile` highlights the occurrences but returns a non-zero exit code when the pattern wasn't matched.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using Grep, you can use Less:

```
less file
```

Search like this: `/pattern` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This will:

1. scroll to first matching line
2. output every line starting from there on
3. highlight all matches

To scroll to next matching line: `n`

To scroll to previous matching line: `N`

To toggle highlighting: <kbd>Esc</kbd> `u`

Also you can change the [highlighting color](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/356335) if you like.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in the *return value* of `grep`, then GNU `sed` is also the way:

`sed '/pattern/h; ${p;x;/./Q0;Q1}'`

You can add to the script modifications to the line, e.g.:

`sed '/pattern/h; ${p;x;/./Q0;Q1}; s/pattern/<\0>/g'`

This checks that `pattern` appears on the current line, and stores it in the *hold buffer* if it is.  At the end of the file (`$`), the last line is printed (`p`), then the hold space and pattern space are swapped (`x`).  Next, the pattern space is tested for emptiness (`/./`), and if it is nonempty, exit with code `0` (`Q0`) otherwise with code 1 (`Q1`).

An alternative is `/pattern/{:a $q1; n; ba}`, which loops after detecting `pattern`, but changing the current line can get tricky with this.  This works by:

- `/pattern/`: the following clause will only be executed when the pattern is detected on a line.
- `:a … ba`: this is defining a label `a` and `b`ranching to it; as is, this is an infinite loop.
- `n`: prints the current line and loads the next one.
- `$q1`: when reaching the end of file (`$`), exit with code 1.

By default, `sed` will exit with code 0, so with this expression, if the pattern is detected, the rest of the file is dumped and an exit code of 1 is produced.

Comment: Thanks for this answer Michaël, and for explaining the script!  Can you also explain how the alternative script works?

Comment: Sure thing @mwfearnley !  See edited answer.

Comment: Nice - thanks!  I wish I could upvote a second time…

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
perl -MTERM::ANSIColor -nle '/pattern/ ? print colored($_, 'color') : print' test
```

Not very portable however, and even if Perl is installed, you may need to download another module.  In addition it will color the entire line, not just the search word.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much easier way to do this for GNU grep but I don't think it's portable (i.e., BSD grep):

In a pipe:

`cat <file> | grep --color=always -z <query>`

On a file:

`grep --color=always -z <query> <file>`

Credit goes to [Cyrus's answer here](https://superuser.com/a/914862/645282).

Comment: This isn’t as good an answer as you (and Cyrus) think.  It has the effect of treating the entire file as a single line.  Therefore, (1) if the file is very large, there may be a possibility of running out of memory, and (2) if the file doesn’t contain the pattern *at all*, then nothing will be output. And you’re right; it isn’t universally available. (But then again, `--color` isn’t [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html) either.)

Comment: What version of grep is this supported on?  On grep 2.5.4, -z doesn't seem available...

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers given so far do provide a **portable** solution.

Here is a portable<sup>1</sup> shell function I [already posted](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106567/2594) in a closed as duplicate question that doesn't require non standard tools or non standard extensions provided with `perl`, `ack`, `ggrep`, `gsed`, `bash` and the likes but only needs a POSIX shell and the POSIX mandatory utilities `sed` and `printf`:

```
grepc()
{
  pattern=$1
  shift
  esc=$(printf "\033")
  sed 's"'"$pattern"'"'$esc'[32m&'$esc'[0m"g' "$@"
}
```

You can use it that way:

```
grepc string_to_search [file ...]
```

The highlight color can be adjusted by using one of these codes in the sed command argument (32m being green here):

```
30m black
31m red
33m yellow
34m blue
35m magenta
36m cyan
37m white
7m reverse video
```

<sup>1</sup> As long as your terminal supports ANSI colors escape sequences.

Answer (score 0):

A `sed` version,
works on both `bash` and `ash`.

```bash
#highlight
hsed(){
    local pattern="$1"
    shift
    local r=`echo -e '\e'[31m`
    local c=`echo -e '\e'[0m`
    sed "s:${pattern//:/\:}:$r\0$c:g" "$@"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OP asked for `grep`, and that is what **I RECOMMEND**; but after trying hard to solve a problem with `sed`, for the record, here is a simple solution with it:

```
sed $'s/main/\E[31m&\E[0m/g' testt.c
```

or

```
cat testt.c | sed $'s/main/\E[31m&\E[0m/g'
```

Will paint `main` in red.

- `\E[31m` : red color start sequence
- `\E[0m` : finished color mark
- `&` : the matched pattern
- `/g` : all words in a line, not just the first
- `$'string'` is bash strings with escaped characters interpreted

---

Regarding **grep**, it also works using `^` (begin of line) instead of `$` (end of line). Example:

```
egrep "^|main" testt.c
```

And just to show this crazy alias that **I DO NOT RECOMMEND**, you can even let the open quotes:

```
alias h='egrep -e"^|'
h main" testt.c
cat testt.c | h main"
```

all work! :) Don't worry if you forget to close the quote, bash will remember you with a "continuing line character".

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the perl answer, but I use it with multiple expressions separated by `|`:

```
tail -F somefile.log | perl -pe 's/\bfirstword\b/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g|s/\bsecondword\b/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g'
```

You and add more words by append multiple `|` (i.e., `|s/\bmorewords\b/\e[1;32m$&\e[0m/g`) and on [What color codes can I use in my bash PS1 prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124407/what-color-codes-can-i-use-in-my-bash-ps1-prompt/124409#124409) you can see more bash the colors to use.