# Command that highlights regex in text?

Tags: bash, highlighting

Is there a command that highlights a certain expression in text?

I'm looking for something like the 'search' function in less, but with normal text output on stdout, instead of the `less` viewer.

Example:

```
$ cat test.txt | highlight "an"
```

> Prospects for **an** orderly NATO withdrawal from
>   Afgh**an**ist**an** suffered two setbacks as President Hamid
>   Karzai dem**an**ded limits on United States troops **an**d the
>   Talib**an** halted peace talks.

It could use color or any other means to highlight the specified regular expression.

Comment: possible duplicate of [`highlight` command](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9360/highlight-command)

Comment: @Gilles, somewhat, but that question had far more complex requirements.

Answer (score 19):

Not sure if this is due to a feature or just some hidden side effect, but this works in GNU `grep` 2.11:

```
grep --color 'an\|' test.txt
```

Comment: It's like you're doing `grep 'an' OR ''`.  The `''` successfully matches nothing at every location in the input.  Only the `an` is highlighted, because you can't highlight the nothing. :-)

Comment: Pure  genius. It did not work for me, but `grep --color -e 'an' -e ' '` (matching for a space, which cannot be colored did the trick). Way better than piping to `sed -e ''/an/s//$(printf "\033[33;1m&\033[0m")/''`, but maybe the latter is more performant. Change 'an' for another search term. ;)

Comment: Wow! I used this to modify the command I used to list all `bashrc` aliases, and now all my aliases are highlighted in red. Super! `alias aliases="clear;cat ~/.bashrc|grep --color \"alias\""`

Answer (score 10):

[ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) has a `--passthru` option that will do this:

```
ack --passthru an test.txt
some_command | ack --passthru an -
```

Comment: (+1) btw: in the Ubuntu repo, the package (and executable) is called `ack-grep` ... (the name `ack` is applied to a Kanji code converter)

Answer (score 2):

You can try out this script of mine. It will let you either specify a file or it takes standard input. You can define a Python regular expression for the text you want to highlight. highlighted text defaults to neon green (hey I use a black background!) But you can change the [ANSI color code](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import re

def highlight_text(text,pat):
    def replacement_funk(matchobj):  return '\x1b[42m%s\x1b[0m'%matchobj.group(0)
    return re.sub(pat,replacement_funk,text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        input = sys.stdin
        pat = sys.argv[1]
    elif len(sys.argv) == 3:
        input = open(sys.argv[2])
        pat = sys.argv[1]
    else:
        sys.stderr.write("colorme pattern [inputfile]")
    text = input.read()
    print highlight_text(text,pat)
```

Here's *an* example.

```
blessburn@blessburn:/tmp$ cat test.txt | ./colorme.py an
```

Prospects for **an** orderly NATO withdrawal from Afgh**an**ist**an** suffered two setbacks as President Hamid Karzai dem**an**ded limits on United States troops **an**d the Talib**an** halted peace talks.

```
blessburn@blessburn:/tmp$ ./colorme.py '(Af.*? |NA[\w]{2})' test.txt
```

Prospects for an orderly **NATO** withdrawal from **Afghanistan** suffered two setbacks as President 
Hamid Karzai demanded limits on United States troops and the Taliban halted peace talks.

Comment: stackexchange bold markup seems funky and thats why the output has extra stars. beats me.

Comment: Use `<b>` if you need to boldface part of a word.

Answer (score 0):

`$cat test.txt | grep --colour=auto -C 100000 an`

"color" also works.  You can also define an alias to make grep always use the option:

`alias grep='grep --colour=auto -C 100000'`

Put the above in /etc/profile.d/ somewhere or your .bashrc or whatever.

Comment: That only prints matching lines.  Frank wants the whole text, just with matches highlighted.

Comment: Added a -C to the above - it works but is a bit messy!

Comment: It works but you should **not** create an alias called grep. With `-C 1000000` you never be able to grep again. Just do `alias highlight='grep --colour=auto -C 1000000'. The cat in the first example is also not necessary: `grep --colour=auto -C 100000 file`.

Comment: I wonder how much memory that's going to consume on a large file.  (I've never looked into how `grep` handles the collection of context lines.)