# Mark occurrences of keyword with a different color

Tags: grep, colors

I have a program which spits out an output to `stdout` like:

```
[OK]      Something is ok
[OK]      Something else is also ok
[FAIL]    This does not look good
[FAIL]    Neither does this
[OK]      At least this is fine
```

To more easy spot the fails from the output I would like to mark the occurrences of the keyword `FAIL` with red *without* discarding the other messages. It would be nice if I could also highlight the `OK` keywords with green :).

Doing a pipe to `egrep --color FAIL` will only show the lines where the `FAIL` keyword is present.

Comment: For a `grep` solution see http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34322

Comment: do you have access to change the source code? is it a bash script?

Comment: @manatwork From the link you specified I clicked my way to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/972370 and with some `tail -f` and `awk` magic, I am good to go =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on `manatwork`'s brilliant little "or nothing" hack in the other question, I offer this, which adds the ability to get *two* highlight colors:

```
 $ myprogram | \
   GREP_COLORS='mt=01;32' egrep --color=always '\[OK\]|' | \
   GREP_COLORS='mt=01;31' egrep --color=always '\[FAIL\]|'
```

That is, you run `grep` over the output twice, with a different `GREP_COLORS` environment variable each time.

The '01;32' value means "bold green", and the other means "bold red". See the Wikipedia [article on ANSI codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) for more ideas.

Alas, this requires GNU grep version 2.5.3 or higher. Older versions of GNU grep supported a different coloring mechanism, but those versions have a bug that prevents you from using the feature in a pipeline more than once. BSD grep emulates the older GNU grep coloring mechanism, and it will work twice in a pipeline, but it yells about "empty sub-expression" due to the `manatwork` hack.

You can remove the backslashes at the end of the first two lines to make it all a single line. I've just split it here for clarity and to play nice with the SE page format.

Comment: Thats brilliant indeed! But for some reason the script does not seem to highlight the second statement on my machine. I'm running CentOS 5.

Comment: What's happening here is that CentOS 5 ships a GNU grep old enough that it doesn't support `GREP_COLORS`, plural. It uses the older `GREP_COLOR` method only, and that method has a bug in it that prevents it from doing the right thing. If you change the command to use `GREP_COLOR=32` and such, it will change the highlight color of the first match only. If you pipe the result through `hexdump -c` you can see that adding the second `egrep` command does do something, but it isn't legal ANSI. Bottom line: you have to upgrade `grep` to get this to work right.

Comment: Haha that's such an insightful comment. Yeah CentOS5 is getting kind of old, as with many OS:s running on old machine spitting out old, god forsaken log messages :) I'll try to see if an upgrade to centos6 is not possible.

Comment: I've just checked my solution on a CentOS 6 box, and it *does* work there, confirming my diagnosis. (Earlier tests were on Ubuntu servers.) EL6 ships with GNU grep 2.6.3. Interestingly, they did also fix the `GREP_COLOR` (singular) bug, even though the feature was deprecated as soon as replaced.

Comment: I can't understand how this solves the problem since the 1st grep will filter out all the "FAIL" so there will be nothing left for the second grep to match..

Comment: @laertis The first `egrep` filters out nothing. It only replaces uncolored "[OK]" with a colored version. Try it.

Comment: @Warren Young you are right, I completely missed the '|' operator at the end of each regex
FYI instead of multiple pipes you can use sed (http://superuser.com/questions/358875/how-to-color-grep-output) or awk (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236005/grep-output-with-multiple-colors)

Answer (score 1):

You can use multitail or ccze for this, both allow configs to describe regexps to match and colors.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Warren Young's answer, I wrote [this Python script](https://github.com/kirubakaran/utilitylib/blob/master/himul) that does the same thing more elegantly and with a lot less typing. So this is how you'd use that script:

```
cat yourfile | himul '\[OK\]' '\[FAIL\]'
```