# cascaded grep matches color code as pattern

Tags: grep, colors

I am piping output of one `grep` command into another `grep`. The first `grep` is using `--color=always`, so that the first match is colored. In practice, that means that the match is enclosed between two color codes, i.e. `\033[1;31m` and `\033[0m`.

Now the problem is if the second pattern is `m`, then it matches the color code of the previous match:

```
echo A B C | grep --color=always A | grep m
```

Similarly, the number `31` would also match.

Is there any way around this?

## UPDATE:

I expected it will go without saying that I need the match to be colored, so getting rid of `--color=always` is not a satisfactory solution for me.

Comment: Stop using `--color=always`?

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9360/22565

Comment: What do you really want to search for and which parts do you want to have colored? Probably you can use only one call to `egrep` and concatenate the patterns with "|".

Comment: @jofel - I don't want to match "A or B" but I want to match "A and B". Thus, `egrep` does not help me here.

Comment: @MartinVegter see [godlygeek's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138944/15241). It describes how you can use egrep to do the final coloring.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to have colored. Which of the two patterns you search for? Using `--color` will color matches exactly as you expect unless you redirect into a file or a pipe, isn't that what you need? You might also want to have a look at the script I've posted in my answer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104402/22222).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what it's worth, this is exactly the reason why `--color` defaults to `--color=auto` and not `--color=always`.

If your goal is "Show me all lines that contain both `A` and `m` and highlight the matching `A` and `m` characters", it seems like the simplest solution would be to do all the highlighting after all of the matching, using one egrep to add the highlighting back in.  Something like:

```
{
    echo "A b";
    echo "A m";
    echo "B m";
    echo "Another m";
} | grep 'A' | grep 'm' | egrep --color 'A|m';
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't use `grep --color=always`, that's precisely why GNU `grep` (and maybe others) also have `grep --color=auto` which is equivalent to `grep --color` alone (from `man grep`):

```
   --color[=WHEN], --colour[=WHEN]
          Surround  the  matched  (non-empty)  strings,  matching   lines,
          context  lines,  file  names,  line  numbers,  byte offsets, and
          separators (for fields and groups of context lines) with  escape
          sequences  to display them in color on the terminal.  The colors
          are  defined  by  the  environment  variable  GREP_COLORS.   The
          deprecated  environment  variable GREP_COLOR is still supported,
          but its setting does not have priority.  WHEN is never,  always,
          or auto.
```

I can't find where this is documented in more detail but it basically detects whether the output of `grep` is a file or a terminal or a pipe or whatever and acts accordingly:

```
$ echo foo | grep --color=always o | grep m
f[01;31mo[m[01;31mo[m
$ echo foo | grep --color=always o >outfile; grep m outfile
f[01;31mo[m[01;31mo[m
```

Compare the above to

```
$ echo foo | grep --color o >outfile; grep m outfile
$ echo foo | grep --color o | grep m 
$
```

So, using the `auto` option will basically only print the colors when you can see them. It is really very clever and works like a charm. So much so, that I have:

```
$ type grep
grep is aliased to `grep --color'
```

Comment: agreed - this can be especially problematic when compiling. any compilation job worth its salt is likely to call grep hundreds of times throughout the process. gcc will get pretty upset if grep keeps spitting terminal escapes at it.

Answer (score 2):

What is the actual use case? If you want to colour code `A` in all lines which also contain `m` you can simply reverse the `grep`s:

```
echo A B C | grep m | grep --color=always A
```

Alternatively, if you're looking for a literal `m` in the original output you'd need to exclude all the colour codes before `grep m` but print the result *with* the colour codes. One way to do this is to use `nl` to number the lines of the output, `grep` for a line number followed by `m`, save only the line numbers from that output, and then use `sed -n` to print only the lines in the colour coded output.