# bash: color matching string

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I am looking for a command which would color a matching string in text. I.e. I am looking for functionality similar to what grep does, but I want to see the complete text not only the matching lines

Can somebody please advise whether such tool exists, or how I could best achieve this ?

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches

Answer (score 3):

Use [ack](http://beyondgrep.com):

```
ack --passthru something /some/file
```

The result will look like this: [image]