# How to highlight a word in the output of "cat"?

Tags: cat, highlighting

I can do the following to see if some word is available in the output of "cat":

```
cat filename | grep word
```

This filters the output and shows only those lines which contain "word". Now, is it possible to only highlight the "word" in the output, without dropping other lines?

Comment: `grep word filename` is clearer and faster. ;) Also, `less` can do this while also providing paging. Just search for `word` by typing `/word` (the term is actually a regular expression, just like `grep`)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can grep for an EOL along with your real query (if you already have an alias for `grep` to use `--color`, as is default in many distributions, you can omit it in the following examples):

```
grep --color=auto 'word\|$' file
```

Since the EOL is not a real character, it won't highlight anything, but it will match all lines.

If you would prefer not to have to escape the pipe character, you can use extended regular expressions:

```
grep -E --color=auto 'word|$' file
```

Comment: Thank you. The highlighted word is currently red on my computer. Is it possible to customize the color as well?

Comment: @Meysam You can do so using the `GREP_COLOR(S)` environment variable. http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html

Comment: Would you mind editing the answer to provide a function for this? I'd love to have `hl` ("highlight") declared in my `.zshrc`. Something like `cat foo.txt | hl bar`. But it should also work when provided a file (`hl "bar" foo.txt`).

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't GNU `grep` available, here is something more portable:

```
grepc()
{
  pattern=$1
  shift
  esc=$(printf "\033")
  sed 's"'"$pattern"'"'$esc'[32m&'$esc'[0m"g' "$@"
}
```

You can customize the color using one of these codes

```
30m black
31m red
32m green
33m yellow
34m blue
35m magenta
36m cyan
37m white
```

Using `7m` instead of a color code will put the string in reverse video.

Comment: Have you tested it? This is what I see in the output: `^[[32mword^[[0m`

Comment: @Meysam Sorry, `^[` is how the escape character is represented at least under `vi`, answer updated to avoid the ambiguity.

Comment: Question closed, so here is a one-liner solution: `cat testt.c | sed $'s/main/\E[31m&\E[0m/g'` Hope it helps