# How to get grep exit code but print all lines?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, grep

I'd like to check whether a line printed by a command contains an error message, but I'd like to also print all the output from the command (for `make` logs). Is there some way to get *all* the output of a command (unmodified) and an exit code based on the contents of that output? The closest workaround I could think about was `my_command | grep -C 99999999 '^Error'`.

This is similar but distinct to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches), since I care about the exit code and don't want colouring.

Comment: How about `grep -E '^Error|$'`?

Comment: @Gnouc that will give $?==0 all the time.

Comment: @jimmij - if you are using bash you can use 'set -o pipefail' and the return code will be not be of grep but the command that failed.

Comment: @DarkHeart OP wants grep exit code, not other command.

Comment: @jimmij - yes sorry, i misread.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `tee` and redirect it to stderr

```
my_command | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q '^Error'
```

It will save `grep` exit status and duplicate all the output to stderr which is visible in console. If you need it in stdout you can redirect it there later like this:

```
( my_command | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q '^Error' ) 2>&1
```

Note that `grep` will output nothing, but it will be on `tee`.

Comment: As soon as grep matches the whole will stop.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with AWK:

```
command 2>&1 | awk '/^Error/{exit_code=1;}/^/ END{ exit !exit_code}'
```

This will print all the output lines and return 0 if it finds `Error` and return 1 if it doesn't.

Comment: I had to add a print 
command 2>&1 | awk '/^Error/{exit_code=1;}/^/{print} END{ exit !exit_code}'

to get this to work. Otherwise it gave mea syntax error. Note sure if this is right.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with ***sed*** as well!

Here's a function to Print all + **Highlight** matches + **Return exit code** (5) if no match found:

```
search_regex()
{
  pattern=$1
  shift
  esc=$(printf "\033")
  sed '/'"${pattern}"'/,${s//'$esc'[32m&'$esc'[0m/g;b};$q5' "$@"
}
```

> $ echo -e "What's up\nMr. Jones?" | search_regex "on\|up"
>
> What's **up**
>   Mr. J**on**es?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it with **sed** if you don't want coloring, i.e. you want exact output:

```
my_command | sed '/^Error/,$b;$q1'
```

And since this is a bit cryptic, I try to explain how it works:

- by default already, `sed` prints every line from stdin to stdout, so we've already achieved our first goal of printing every line
- `/^Error/,$` then defines a range from the line that matches the pattern `/^Error/` to the end of the file (`$` means the last line).
- on this range, execute command `b`. `b` branches (i.e. jumps) to a label. If the label is omitted, it branches to end of script. `sed` returns with status code 0.
- if no line matches the pattern `/^Error`, the range command is not executed, thus we're not jumping to the end of script. Instead, the next command is executed: `$q1`.
- `$q1` simply means to run command `q1` on the last line (`$`). `q1` ends the script, with status code `1`