# How can I pipe a command to grep and get the exit status while still sending command output to stdout and errors to stderr?

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection

**Concrete use case:**

I'm trying to `curl` a URL with `-v`, output the verbose debug information to stderr as normal, output the response body to stdout as normal, but also check for the presence of a regexp in the response with `grep`, and exit nonzero if it's not found. The simplest form of the command is

```bsh
curl -v "${url}" | grep -q "${pattern}"
```

but `grep` consumes the response body.

**What I've tried:**

1. I've looked at “[Convince grep to output all lines, not just those with matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches)”, which would suggest things like:

   ```bsh
   curl -v "${url}" | grep --color -E "${pattern}|$"
   ```

   but this only color-highlights the match, it doesn't get you a nonzero exit code if `pattern` is not present.
2. I've also looked at “[How to get grep exit code but print all lines?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158389/how-to-get-grep-exit-code-but-print-all-lines)”, which suggests:

   ```bsh
   curl -v "${url}" | tee /dev/stderr | grep -q "${pattern}"
   ```

   which exits with the exit code from `grep` and does output the response body; but it outputs the response body to stderr, and I want to keep `curl`'s stderr and stdout streams separate and intact.
3. Following “[Direct output to pipe and stdout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273118/direct-output-to-pipe-and-stdout)”, I tried

   ```bsh
   curl -v "${url}" | tee >(grep -q "${pattern}")
   ```

   but while this outputs everything, and correctly separates the stdout and stderr streams, it  discards the `grep` exit code.

**Current workaround:**

So far, the only thing I've been able to come up with is to stick the response body in a temporary file:

```bsh
curl -v "${url}" | tee /tmp/response
grep -q "${pattern}" /tmp/response
```

This gets me the correct output and the correct exit code.

But surely there's a way to do this as a single pipeline, without the temporary file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second answer is on the right track. 
Try

```
{ curl -v "${url}" | tee /dev/fd/3 | grep -q "${pattern}";} 3>&1
```

Brief explanation:

- The `3>&1` duplicates file descriptor 1 (standard output)
  onto file descriptor 3 (the lowest one that doesn’t have a standard usage). 
  This refers to the standard output of the entire pipeline
  (i.e., the entire command line). 
  The new file descriptor (3) is in effect for the entire pipeline.

  You could use any number — at least any number up to 9. 
  The [POSIX Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) specification,
  [section 2.7 Redirection](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07), says

  > … all implementations shall support at least 0 to 9 …

  implying that a POSIX-compliant shell
  might not recognize numbers larger than 9. 
  And [`bash(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION) says

  > Redirections using file descriptors greater than 9
  > should be used with care …
- `tee /dev/fd/3` tells `tee` to write to file descriptor 3 —
  so it hooks `tee` up to the standard output of the pipeline.

  - You must use the same number here
    as you used in the `n>&1` directive.
  - Filenames like `/dev/fd/n`
    might not work on non-Linux operating systems.

  Note that this happens independent of the standard output *of `tee`,*
  which is the pipe to the `grep`.

Stéphane Chazelas [points out](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/685984/686008?noredirect=1#comment1296528_686008):

> `grep -q` exits when the pattern is found,
> which would cause `tee` to die if it writes output after that. 
> The GNU implementation of `tee` at least has a `-p`
> for it to ignore the SIGPIPE
> and carry on writing to the targets that can still get output. 
> Also note that some shells only wait for the last component of pipelines
> so here, would carry with the rest of the script
> as soon as `grep -q` has found the pattern …

As a formality 
I verified the first point (the pipeline can be terminated prematurely
if the pattern is matched)<sup>1</sup>.

I offer this enhanced solution to address both of the issues:

```
{ curl -v "${url}" | tee /dev/fd/3 | { grep -q "${pattern}" && cat > /dev/null;} } 3>&1
```

Notes:

- If the data stream *doesn’t* match the pattern,
  then `grep` will read the entire stream (i.e., its input),
  and so the problem won’t arise. 
  And, in this case, `grep` will “fail”, and so, because of the `&&`,
  the `cat` will not run,
  and the compound command will return the exit code from `grep`;
  i.e., failure (i.e., no match).
- If the data stream ***does*** match the pattern,
  then (as pointed out by Stéphane)
  `grep` will exit when it matches the pattern,
  and not read the entire input (i.e., the output from `curl | tee`). 
  But in this case, `grep` will “succeed”, and so, because of the `&&`,
  the `cat` *will* run, and it will soak up the rest of the data (until EOF). 
  This will ensure that `tee` will be able
  to write the entire data stream to the pipe,
  and the pipeline (i.e., the whole command line)
  won’t terminate until all of `curl`’s output has been processed.

There’s technically still a problem with this:
if the data stream matches the pattern and `grep` “succeeds”,
then the pipeline’s exit status will be the exit status from `cat`. 
I don’t know
why `(pipe) | cat > /dev/null` would ever fail,
but it’s theoretically possible. 
To guard against that case, I offer:

```
{ curl -v "${url}" | tee /dev/fd/3 | if grep -q "${pattern}"; then cat > /dev/null; true; else false; fi; } 3>&1
```

which explicitly returns true if `grep` succeeds and false if it fails. 
______________
<sup>1</sup> The `-p` option to `tee` was added
in [release 8.24 (2015-07-03)](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob_plain;f=NEWS;hb=88a7228bb2aafb2efb5a7b5de5348ac8105ad9b1).

---

For any of the above variations,
if you want to ***pipe*** the output from `curl` somewhere else,
just add the pipe at the end of the command line, as you normally would:

```
{ curl …; fi; } 3>&1 | lpr
```

But, if you want to ***redirect*** it to a file,
you must insert the output redirection *before* the `3>&1`:

```
{ curl …; fi; } > output_file 3>&1
```

Recall that “pipe into a file” is incorrect terminology.

Comment: `grep -q` exits when the pattern is found, which would cause `tee` to die if it writes output after that. The GNU implementation of `tee` at least has a `-p` for it to ignore the SIGPIPE and carry on writing to the targets that can still get output. Also note that some shells only wait for the last component of pipelines so here, would carry with the rest of the script as soon as `grep -q` has found the pattern even if `curl` has not finished downloading.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Any problems with this?

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Does `/dev/fd/3` just get me an arbitrary third file descriptor, then? That's the piece I was missing, thanks.

Comment: I have added some explanation.

Comment: While opening `/dev/fd/3` gets you a dup of fd  3 on most systems, on Linux-based systems or Cygwin, that reopens the file fd 3 points to anew, so it won't work if stdout goes to a socket for instance and if stdout  is for instance pointing to the end of a log file opened in append more, you'll end up clobbering that log file. While it wouldn't help for sockets, with `tee -a`, you'd at least avoid clobbering files. See also `{ tee >(grep -q... && cat); wait "$!"; }` in newer versions of bash.

Answer (score 3):

If there's nothing special about `grep` here, maybe use awk to do the pattern matching instead:

```
curl -v "${url}" | awk -v p="$pattern" '$0 ~ p {found=1} {print} END {exit ! found}'
```

- `-v p="$pattern"` sets the awk variable `p` to the value of the shell variable `pattern`
- `$0 ~ p {found=1}` sets the awk variable `found` to 1 if the line matched regex in `p` variable.
- `{print}` - prints all lines (since no condition is given for this block)
- `END {exit ! found}`  - at the end of input, exit with status of negated value of `found` (so 0 if the pattern was matched, 1 otherwise).

Awk and grep support different regexes, so you might need to change the pattern.

Comment: Avoid `-v` for passing regexps as it mangles backslashes. It's better to use the environment (`P=$pattern awk '$0 ~ ENVIRON["P"]...'`)