# Bash: Show the contents of a text file, with every occurrence of a word highlighted

Tags: linux, bash

How can I show the contents of a text file, with every occurrence of a word highlighted?

Comment: The question is not really understandable.
What are you trying to achieve ? Vim depending of configuration is doing what you are looking when you are searching a word in an open file.

Comment: @netmonk With all due respect, what part of *"Show the contents of a text file, with every occurrence of a word highlighted"* do you not understand?

Comment: Possibly related: [Convince grep to output all lines, not just those with matches](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches)

Comment: Well, your answer is supposing he wants to do it in an interactive shell. No precision so far about any context. My `vim` suggestion can be valid so far, as far as information are missing.
That is why, the original question is not really understandable.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -C $(wc -l foo.txt | cut -d" " -f 1) --color word foo.txt
```

Where `foo.txt` is the file path and `word` is the search term.  If you are not familiar with `grep`, beware the search term is actually a *regular expression*.  This doesn't matter if `word` is purely alphanumeric, but certain characters such as `[` and `]` have a special meaning in a regular expression and if you want to use them literally, prefix `\`.  Also, this passes through the shell, so `$` will do funny things if not also escaped with `\`.

You can include spaces in `word` if you enclose it in quotes.

The other commands used here are `wc` and `cut`, which will almost always be stock on a POSIX system such as GNU/Linux.  They have `man` pages that explain their use.

Comment: One advantage of this general method is that the `-F` option may be added; then *`word`* is interpreted as literal text to match rather than a regular expression. (The primary method given in [my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340331/11938)--and [jacksonh's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/367/11938) to the [related question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/366/11938)--don't readily support that enhancement.) An alternative to parsing the output of `wc` is to prevent it from ever knowing the filename by using input redirection instead of a path argument: `$(wc -l < foo.txt)`

Comment: @EliahKagan - will all due respect to _goldilocks_, you don't need to read the file twice, count the lines and use a non-standard option like `-C` just to be able to grep for fixed strings _and_ print the non-matching lines too. It's [much simpler than that](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340417).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with just `grep`. Where `file.txt` is your file and *`word`* is the text you want to highlight, you can use:

```bash
grep --color -E 'word|$' file.txt
```

This matches and highlights occurrences of *`word`*. In addition, it alternatively (`|`) matches and highlights the empty string at the end of each line (`$`). But since that string is empty, no extra text is actually highlighted.

Matching `$` in addition to *`word`* serves the purpose of ensuring every line contains a match. Then `grep` prints every line, even without the `-A`, `-B`, or `-C` options or any calls to other utilities.

The `-E` flag makes `grep` interpret its pattern argument as [a POSIX extended regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended) (ERE). Depending on what characters are in *`word`*, you may want to make it use a basic regular expression (BRE) instead. Although alternation with `|` is not officially part of POSIX basic regular expressions, `grep` implementations often support it as an extension with `\|`:<sup>1</sup>

```bash
grep --color 'word\|$' file.txt
```

In particular, on GNU/Linux systems you have GNU Grep, which supports this. If you are relying on `--color`, you can likely rely on this behavior too.

These commands are simpler than the way in [goldilocks's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340322/11938). But the technique in that answer does have a distinct advantage in some circumstances. Since the methods here use `|` and `$`, they have to really be regular expressions, rather than fixed strings. However, with [goldilocks's method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/340322/11938), you can add the `-F` flag. Then `word` can contain whatever text you like, even `\`, provided you quote *`word`* properly to ensure the shell passes it to `grep` unmodified.

For example, you can use:

```bash
grep --color -FC "$(wc -l < file.txt)" 'word' file.txt
```

For further reading, see [Convince grep to output all lines, not just those with matches](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366/convince-grep-to-output-all-lines-not-just-those-with-matches) (as [steeldriver](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/65304/steeldriver) [suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340320/what-would-be-the-command-in-linux-for-show-the-contents-of-a-text-file-with-e#comment601603_340320)).

---

<sup>1</sup>As far as [the standard (IEEE Std 1003.1-2008)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html) specifies, alternation is a feature of ERE (via `|`), but it is *not* a feature of BRE. But [implementations are permitted](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799//xrat/V4_xbd_chap09.html#tag_21_09_03_08) to interpret `\|` as they wish, and many interpret it as alternation:

> Some implementations have extended the BRE syntax to add alternation.
>   For example, the subexpression "`\(foo$\|bar\)`" would match either
>   "`foo`" at the end of the string or "`bar`" anywhere. The extension is
>   triggered by the use of the undefined "`\|`" sequence.

Comment: @Fox That *was* unclear--thanks for noticing and drawing my attention to this. I've reworded and added an explanatory footnote. In addition to the syntax for alternation varying between dialects, my understanding is BRE--so far as it's formally defined--really doesn't have alternation. The `\|` syntax is allowed as a non-standard extension to BRE and widely implemented. Please let me know if you believe I'm mistaken on this or if the post remains unclear. (Of course, as you say, alternation is *not* a vendor-provided extension of ERE--every conforming ERE implementation *must* implement it.)

Comment: BRE (as defined by the standard) are a subset of true regular expressions. The update and footnote are great in explaining that